# POST request to YouTube for reporting/deleting spam comments (Without API)

Tags: python, request, youtube, http-post, spam-prevention

I´m trying to report/delete spam comments (with python) on YouTube

When checking the console after reporting a comment I get this POST request:

https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/flag/flag?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&prettyPrint=false

On the browser, it gets you a 405 ERROR because of the GET request.
When I try to send the same request with POST using selenium-requests (from python) I get a 400 ERROR.

Am I missing some parameters maybe, if so... how can I know which ones are? Or that type of request is not possible to send.

```
from seleniumrequests import Chrome
URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
v=dvecqwfU6xw&lc=Ugxw_nsUNUor9AUEBGp4AaABAg.9fDfvkgiqtW9fDkE2r6Blm"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
user = pathlib.Path().home()
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir= 
{user}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/")
driver= Chrome('chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
driver.get(URL)
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
resp = driver.request('POST', 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/flag/get_form?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&prettyPrint=false')
print(resp)#<Response [400]>
```

Note: It's important for me not to use the API because of the 10k quota limit.
Thanks!

Comment: Probably you're missing parameters. Please [edit] and add the code you're using. Also, you're reporting/flagging comments while you're logged in? - I think this is a key to consider

Comment: I've updated the code, hopefully, I might just be missing something, and yes driver options load my profile which means it would open the chrome browser with my account logged-in

Comment: Please note that you've included a `key` parameter in your code.  Was this intentional?

Comment: Well, I copied that from the console and tried to replicate the request but with code, shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: It seems clear to me that just by being connected and on the webpage of the video with the comment pinned that calling the `get_form` endpoint as you do won't work, as *the endpoint doesn't know which comment you want to delete*. Usually there are some data other than the URL to provide to YouTube to do such things. You can either click on the `Delete` button using Selenium or you can reverse-engineer using your `Network` tab of your web-browser the request sent to YouTube when you click on such `Delete` button.

Comment: maybe first `print( resp.text )` to if it sends some details about problem. PRobably it needs some extra data in `data=`, or some `cookies` or `headers`.

Comment: the key sent in the link as a request is actually the comment ID, that's why I think it should be enough for it to flag it/delete it. I'm really trying to look up for the parameters or data that I might be missing on my request but I really don't know how. When I print resp.text I get a bunch of nonsense: ‼◄☺�rS�Q��o�����►♠�j0��☻��/i�(↓���&↓G�n‼���tc�]Ư�:♣Y�u����E☺;�>▲���&�k_▲☺L↑�����|��↔"I�<�e�B☺8�→G��u��ƞ�����ϫ8ڻ!�&ʧ�m`�)�

Comment: Also... I was trying to delete by manually making selenium to press on the buttons and delete/flag the specific comment (which I know the ID) but It didn't seem to work since the button is hidden until you hover the comment with your mouse. Can someone help me on this if there is no other solution?